# Is it sufficient to consider the uncharged dark matter and a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry to prevent its decay into photons?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model, axion

Higgs boson, though electrically neutral, can decay to produce a pair of photons i.e., have electromagnetic interactions. See the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411580/higgs-is-neutral-but-decays-into-photons-why). Therefore, it appears that making dark matter electrically uncharged is not enough to prevent its decay into photons. For example, @marmot points out that axions can decay into photons. However, dark matter models usually also involve $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetries to prevent the decay of dark matter particles. Then how is it possible that the dark matter, like the axion, can still decay?

Comment: same story with Z-boson. This is because Z and Higgs are electroweak multiplets, or parts of multiplets. Photon is also part of EW multiplet.

Comment: @marmot You mean $\mathbb{Z}_2$ type symmetry would forbid its decay into photons? My question is this. While building a model for dark matter, is it enough to consider the dark matter to be uncharged in order to prevent its decay into photons?

Comment: In many models decay of dark matter to photons is forbidden by giving it some conserved exotic quantum number, see for example [Wikipedia on the LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightest_supersymmetric_particle).

Comment: No, I did not read your question carefully. DM can decay into photons. An example is the axion, whose decay rate is hover tiniest.

Comment: @marmot Not your fault. I edited the question.

Comment: A $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry can make the DM absolutely stable, so it can't decay in anything, including photons.

Comment: @marmot So axion decay is not protected by imposing a $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: The (QCD) axion does not have $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry. In fact, I guess it is next-to-impossible to have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for an axion which you have an approximate shift symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Both Higgs and (hypothetically) axions do not decay directly into photons, but indirectly through "virtual loops" involving other particles.

(Have a look also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/322207/axion-coupling-to-photons/322485#322485).)

So, yes, if something doesn't carry electric charge then it cannot directly "touch" photons :)